# How extract (changeable variable) word & number using regular expression matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I have more than 10k text files look similar like this, all of them are similar in format but not in size, sometime is bigger or smaller.

```
[{u'language': u'english', u'area': 3825.8953168044045, u'class': u'machine printed', u'utf8_string': u'troia', u'image_id': 428035, u'box': [426.42422762784093, 225.33333055900806, 75.15151515151516, 50.909090909090864], u'legibility': u'legible', u'id': 1056659}, {u'language': u'na', u'area': 24201.285583103767, u'id': 1056660, u'image_id': 428035, u'box': [223.99998520359847, 249.57575480143228, 172.12121212121215, 140.6060606060606], u'legibility': u'illegible', u'class': u'machine printed'}]
```

I want to extract two changeable variable in every text using regular expression.

The output should be like this

```
box  = [223.99998520359847, 249.57575480143228, 172.12121212121215, 140.6060606060606]
box1 = .. sometime there is more than one
```

& 
second output

```
word = troia 
word1 =  ... sometime there is more than one word
```

My code 1:  for the word extraction

```
fid = fopen('text1.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fid);

C = C{:};

Lia = ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C,'utf8_string'));

output = [C{find(Lia)}];
expression = 'u''utf8_string'': u+'
matchStr = regexp(output, expression,'match');
```

My code 1 result give me only the

```
utf8_string
```

My code 2: for the box number extraction

```
s = sprintf('text_.txt'); 
fid = fopen(s);
tline = fgetl(fid);

C = regexp(tline,'u''box'': +\[([0-9\. ,]+)\]','tokens');
C = cellfun(@(x) x{1},C,'UniformOutput',false)';
M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x', cat(1,C2{:}),'UniformOutput',false));
```

This code 2 is running but not with every text something i got this error

```
Error using cat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent
```

Comment: Your error is because of different sizes of concatenated arrys, [read here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95215-why-do-i-get-the-error-cat-arguments-dimensions-are-not-consistent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not insist on regexp: The input strings looks like json, so the following short code does even more than you want:

```
% Read the whole file
s = fileread('test.txt');
% Remove the odd u'
s = strrep(s, 'u''', '''');
% Replace ' by "
s = strrep(s, '''', '"');
% See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565
t = parse_json(s);
```

Now t a is cell object containing structs with the data. So

```
word = t{1}.utf8_string;
box = cell2mat(t{1}.box);
```

will give you the first word and box. If you have a newer Matlab version you can probably use `jsondecode` instead of `parse_json`.

Comment: Thank you very much, great help with simple code, regexp was the wrong approach for this problem.